# How to extract string from python list?

Tags: python

Assuming a python array "myarray" contains:

```
mylist = [u'a',u'b',u'c']
```

I would like a string that contains all of the elements in the array, while preserving the double quotes like this (notice how there are no brackets, but parenthesis instead):

```
result = "('a','b','c')"
```

I tried using `",".join(mylist)`, but it gives me the result of "a,b,c" and eliminated the single quotes.

Comment: How do you intend to convert the Unicode to bytes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were quite close, this is how I would've done it:

```
result = "('%s')" % "','".join(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
>>> mylist = [u'a',u'b',u'c']
>>> str(tuple(map(str, mylist)))
"('a', 'b', 'c')"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `repr()`?

```
>>> repr(tuple(mylist))
"(u'a', u'b', u'c')"
```

More info on [repr()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = "({})".format(",".join(["'{}'".format(char) for char in mylist]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [u'a', u'b', u'c']
>>> str(tuple([str(e) for e in l]))
"('a', 'b', 'c')"
```

Calling `str` on each element `e` of the list `l` will turn the Unicode string into a raw string. Next, calling `tuple` on the result of the list comprehension will replace the square brackets with parentheses. Finally, calling `str` on the result of that should return the list of elements with the single quotes enclosed in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation:

```
mylist = [u'a',u'b',u'c']
result = "\"{0}\"".format(tuple(mylist))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
"('a', 'b', 'c')"
```